# Spigot infinite Firework

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm currently working on a plugin that should freeze entitys. I already did most of them but I'm now really messed up with fireworks. I already have a function that teleports all the "moving" entitys back to their location every tick.

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(instance, () -> {
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        //teleporting and setting velocity
        if (e instanceof Firework) {
            Firework f = (Firework) e;
            //TODO how can I make it NOT disappear after one or two seconds
        }
    }
});
```

Now the problem with fireworks is, that they automatically get removed after they triggered some sort of lifespan and detonate. I just don't want that if the entities are frozen.

I already tried `f.setTicksLived(1);` but sadly this won't change anything at all. *(I really don't think this function works how it is supposed to do)*

My next approach was to change the power of the firework.

```java
FireworkMeta fm = f.getFireworkMeta();
fm.setPower(127);
f.setFireworkMeta(fm);
```

But since 127 is the maxial allowed number for `.setPower()` the firework will still vanish after a minute or two.

I really want the firework to be visible for an indefinite timespan. It should not disappear at all and launching a new firework every like 10 seconds is not an option since it would always play the launch-sound which I simply don't want.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Entity Data section of the Minecraft [Firework Rocket](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Firework_Rocket) page, Firework Rockets have the following NBT data (among others):

- integer `Life` is the number of ticks the rocket has been flying for.
- integer `LifeTime` is the number of ticks `Life` must be greater than or equal to in order to explode.

AFAIK neither of these values can be modified using the [`Firework`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Firework.html) entity or [`FireworkMeta`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/meta/FireworkMeta.html) classes provided by Bukkit.

However, by modifying the NBT data of the Firework Rocket entity directly, we are able to change these values:

```
net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R1.Entity mcFireworkEntity = ((CraftEntity) bukkitFireworkEntity).getHandle();
NBTTagCompound tag = new NBTTagCompound();

mcFireworkEntity.c(tag); // gets the firework to dump nbt data into our 'tag' object

// set the entity life flag to 1.
tag.setInt("Life", 1);
// you can optionally also set the `LifeTime` value to the maximum setting as well
// tag.setInt("LifeTime", 2147483647)

// write the tag back into the entity. This needs to happen every game tick
// because minecraft will increase this value by 1 every tick
((EntityLiving)mcFireworkEntity).a(tag); //
```

[`NBTTagCompound`](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/master/net/minecraft/server/NBTTagCompound.java) is part of the decompiled minecraft server [repository](https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev) provided by bukkit (not sure if by default, may need some messing around on your part).